# select with value in table and show onChange

Tags: php, jquery, select, onchange

I have `select` input with `value` from database, i will show other `input` value when select `onChange`.

```js
function showModel(id) {
    if (id === "") {
        $("input[name=color]").val("");
    } else if ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
}
```

```html
<select onchange='showModel(this.value)' name="model" class="form-control" required="">
  <option value="">- SELECT -</option>
  <?php
    $qry = $db->query("SELECT name_model, color FROM product ");
    while ($fet = $qry->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $fet['name_model']; ?>"><?php echo $fet['name_model']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">
```

when i change `select` its show `color` data from table

Comment: Could please specify what's your purpose?

Comment: When i select the dropdown, its will show value (value from table by value selected) in `<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">`

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to select elements by they value?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the option value to `name_model`, set it to color instead. Then it should work as expected.

```
<option value="<?php echo $fet['color']; ?>"><?php echo $fet['name_model']; ?></option>
```

Your script is missing the else part.

```
function showModel(id){
    if (id === "") {
        $("input[name=color]").val("");
    } else {
        $("input[name=color]").val(id);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since `showModel` actually gets the value from the `onchange`, and the value can be empty (`''`) all you need is this:

```
function showModel(id){
      $("input[name=color]").val(id);
}
```

Comment: That solution is more charming than mine XD

Comment: I never tought a dog could write better code than me.

Comment: I'm no ordinary dog. I'm Jameson

Answer (score 0):

**Using javascript onchange function.**

The filename.php is the name of the php file of your server. In php file all you have to do is get the model value by $_POST['model'] and do the DB operation and echo the color name in the response.

```js
function showModel(value){
  if (value === "") {
    $("input[name=color]").val("");
  } else{    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'filename.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'model='+value,
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        $("input[name=color]").val(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange='showModel(this.value)' name="model" class="form-control" required="">
  <option value="">- SELECT -</option>
  <option value="1">Blue</option>
  <option value="2">Yellow</option>
  <option value="3">Red</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">
```

**Another way using jquery `.on("change"` event listener.**

```js
$("select[name='model']").on("change",function(){
  var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
  if (selectedvalue === "") {
    $("input[name=color]").val("");
  } else{
    $("input[name=color]").val(selectedvalue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="model" class="form-control" required="">
  <option value="">- SELECT -</option>
  <option value="1">Blue</option>
  <option value="2">Yellow</option>
  <option value="3">Red</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">
```

Comment: sorry guys with my question that disconcerting, the `$("input[name=color]").val(selectedvalue);` `selectedvalue` data from table, not from value selected. if i selected model `model 123` then show color 'blue' . the color is dinamic by `model` from table (in database)

Comment: On change of the select box you have to make an ajax call.. in ajax call you have to pass the selected value from select box ane using db operation you have to fetch value from db accordingly and assign the value in text box..

Comment: i think that, but would you show ajax for me please . :D

Comment: Please check first snippet. I have places a sample ajax code. The filename.php is the name of the php file of your server. In php file all you have to do is get the model value by $_POST['model'] and do the DB operation and echo the color name in the response.

Comment: thanks Rahul, just add `json` for return data. but, when i select the `select box` (example: blue selected). its change all `$("input[name=color]").val(data);` .i want to change only `$("input[name=color]").val(data);` in `clone` how to fix it ?

Comment: To achieve it you have to made a change in your code. You should have to user the other way which i mentioned in my answer and have to fire ajax call in it and have to place $(this).next("input[name=color]").val(data) instead of $("input[name=color]").val(data); in it.

Answer (score 0):

No IF. It's the same result:

```js
function showModel(id){
  $("input[name=color]").val(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange='showModel(this.value)' name="model" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="">- SELECT -</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="321">321</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if i'm right but it work ! ;-)

```js
$('select[name=model]').on('change', function() {
  var valModel = $(this).val();
  if (valModel != "- SELECT -") {
    $("input[name=color]").val(valModel);
  } else {
    $("input[name=color]").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="model" class="form-control" required="">
    <option>- SELECT -</option>
    <option value="Model_1">Model_1</option> 
    <option value="Model_2">Model_2</option> 
    <option value="Model_3">Model_3</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="color" readonly="">
```